# SSRS: How can I bring forward data label from bar and line chart

Tags: reporting-services

I have a bar and line chart in the report.

I only need data label of bar chart to be shonw on the graph.

But the issue is that Line graph's line is covering some of the data label.

How can I bring forward the data label?

I still need the line to be in front of the bar chart tho..

I tried with smart label adjustment but it doesn't bring data label of bar chart forward than the lines.